# jade and client side javascript

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I just started learning Express for nodejs using jade as a rendering engine, i have views and routes

Here are my views

layout.jade

```
  doctype html
    html
      head
        title= title
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
        link(href='/themes/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')
        script(src='/javascripts/mygridwidjet.js', type='text/javascript')
      body
    block content
```

index.jade

```
extends layout

    block content
      h1= title
      p Welcome to #{title}
          .content-container-fluid
          .row
              .cols-sample-area
                  #Grid
```

and here are my routes

index.js

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Football Archive' });
};
```

and i wrote my client side javascript which interacts with the `#Grid`

now i am really confused about where to put the client side javascript.

ps: i am a total noob, sorry if this question is so stupid.

Comment: Your client-side javascript is in the `javascripts/mygridwidjet.js`, isn't it?

Comment: @alex no but in this /javascripts/clienttest.js

Comment: Did you include it into template like `mygridwidjet.js` is included? Is express.js set up to serve static files?

Comment: @alex mygridwidjet.js is just a library, the javascript that i dont know where to put uses that library, no! is that all i have to do?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must put it in the folder `public/` (create it if it does not exists)

```
myapp
 |
 |-node_modules/
 |   |-express/
 |   |-socket.io/
 |
 |-public/
 |   |-javascripts/
 |   |    |-mygridwidjet.js
 |   |-...
 | 
 |-server.js
```

Here is a more complex example (my app) : https://github.com/CraftYourModCorporation/RedstoneHub